# XPlot trying to visualize data

Tags: plot, f#, jupyter-notebook

I am having a really hard time trying to visualize some data using f#. I am trying to achieve this on Linux environment using `jupyter notebooks` that I am running on localhost. I am following [this article](https://medium.com/luteceo-software-chemistry/statistical-analysis-using-f-and-jupyter-notebooks-2e2f31ee4cc1).
Everything seems to be fine, I managed to load all the needed script files, such as `MathNet.Numerics` and `XPlot`. I don't get any errors, my terminal is fine as well, kernel is in place. I wonder why am I not getting any graph reprisentation after I run my code?

[image: It only says that I get back Xplot.Plotly.PlotlyChart]

It only says that I get back `Xplot.Plotly.PlotlyChart`, what about the actual graph? I am not sure if this would be enough to help me out, if not, let me know and will fill in other information. I tried different browsers as well, didn't help.

Actual code:

```
#load @"<project-root>/.paket/load/net45/MathNet.Numerics.fsx"
#load @"<project-root>/.paket/load/net45/MathNet.Numerics.FSharp.fsx"
#load @"<project-root>/.paket/load/net45/XPlot.Plotly.fsx"


open System
open System.Linq
open MathNet.Numerics.Distributions
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra
open XPlot.Plotly

let n = 40
let nbsim = 1000
let lambda = 0.2
let randomSeed = 1111

let exponential = Exponential.Samples(new Random(randomSeed), lambda) |> Seq.take (n* nbsim) |> List.ofSeq

let m = Matrix<float>.Build.DenseOfRowMajor(nbsim, n, exponential)

let means = m.RowSums() / (float n)
means.Average()

let historyTrace = 
  Histogram(
    x = means,
    xbins = 
      Xbins(
        start = 2.8,
        ``end`` = 7.75,
        size = 0.08
      ),
    marker =
      Marker(
        color = "yellow",
        line =
          Line(
            color = "grey",
            width = 1
          )
      ),
    opacity = 0.75,
    name = "Exponental distribution"      
  ) :> Trace

let meanTrace = 
  Scatter(
    x = [5; 5],
    y = [0; 60],
    name = "Theorical mean"
  ) :> Trace

// Or plain historyTrace below
[historyTrace; meanTrace]
|> Chart.Plot
|> Chart.WithXTitle("Means")
|> Chart.WithYTitle("Frequency")
|> Chart.WithTitle("Distribution of 1000 means of exponential distribution")
```

Please note that `#load` statements include `<project-root>` placeholder. I am using Paket to generate scripts for `#load`.

Comment: Please, include the actual code so I can copy paste it.

Comment: @AMieres, updated original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me in the F# Azure Notebook.

Make sure to include this in a cell before you invoke the chart

```
#load "XPlot.Plotly.Paket.fsx"
#load "XPlot.Plotly.fsx"
open XPlot.Plotly
```

This is a quote from FSharp for Azure Notebooks:

> Note that we had to #load two helper scripts in order to load the
>   assemblies we need and to enable Display to show our charts. The first
>   downloads and installs the required Paket packages, and the second
>   sets up Display support.

The key line for you is: `#load "XPlot.Plotly.fsx"`
That is the one that lets you display the chart in the notebook.

This is my code in the Azure notebook:

```
// cell 1
#load "XPlot.Plotly.Paket.fsx"
#load "XPlot.Plotly.fsx"
```

---

```
// cell 2
Paket.Package [ "MathNet.Numerics"
                "MathNet.Numerics.FSharp"  ]
#load "Paket.Generated.Refs.fsx"
```

---

```
// cell 3
open System
open System.Linq
open MathNet.Numerics.Distributions
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra
open XPlot.Plotly

let n = 40
let nbsim = 1000
let lambda = 0.2
let randomSeed = 1111

let exponential = Exponential.Samples(new Random(randomSeed), lambda) |> Seq.take (n* nbsim) |> List.ofSeq

let m = Matrix<float>.Build.DenseOfRowMajor(nbsim, n, exponential)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one question though, could you tell me where did you find `XPlot.Plotly.Paket.fsx` file? I cannot seem to find it nor in my repo, nor on the internet.

Comment: It seems to be available in Azure Notebook.

Comment: My recomendation is that you sign in for Azure Notebook. Create a Library. You can clone my solution here: https://notebooks.azure.com/amieres/libraries/Public . If you use the terminal option you can even look at the installation and the files are in a directory called: `IFSharp/bin`

Comment: Additional question @Amieres , do you know why these cells in notebook are so important? If you try to add whole code into one cell, it doesn't work as expected, if you distribute it between cells- it does.

One more thing. This `XPlot.Plotly.Paket.fsx` works from Azure notebook, but what about hosting jupyter notebooks on localhost? Is there a way to actually `#load` it from within the localhost? I was really eager to make it work from Linux environment, and this library is kinda the last hickup I have, if I get that solved, I am happy. :(

Comment: I suspect that it is because those initial cells download and install the necessary components that are needed to be able to compile the subsequent cells. Azure notebook creates some Linux instances to run the notebook, try to investigate how they work by going to the terminal option, there you can see the file `IFSharp/bin/XPlot.Plotly.Paket.fsx` and maybe even copy paste to your Linux instance.

Comment: The files are here: https://github.com/fsprojects/IfSharp/tree/master/src/IfSharp

Comment: This the zip file, check that you have the same version V3.0.1: https://github.com/fsprojects/IfSharp/releases/download/v3.0.1/IfSharp.v3.0.1.zip

Comment: Thanks @AMieres! This cell approach is really frustrating, still hardly have any idea on why is this an order of functions, but I managed to get it to work on localhost. I completely forgot about `IFSharp` that I downloaded couple days ago, and right, it holds some `.fsx` files I needed.